# @NotThreadSafe not found error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

0.3 code.

```
@NotThreadSafe
public class VoicemailPlaybackFragment extends Fragment {
//
}
```

I am getting compile time error as "NotThreadSafe cannot be resolved to a type"
i.e, `@NotThreadSafe` not imported
can anyone help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That annotation is not in the standard Java or Android codebases yet.

Depending on how and why you are using this, you should either add some third-party JAR containing it to your classpath, or just add a copy to your codebase.

[This page](http://mavenhub.com/c/javax/annotation/concurrent/NotThreadSafe) lists a few products that include the annotation.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C, can you please suggest the jar which has the annotation "NotThreadSafe"

Comment: All of the ones in the linked page.

Comment: Thanks, I included the jar http://www.findjar.com/jar/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar.html its fine....